# Скачать изображения с сайта

Tags: парсер

Есть сайт https://thepaperwall.com/category/cars

Хочу скачать все изображения машин по ссылке. Проблема в том, что по этой ссылке они маленькие и нужно каждую открывать отдельно и качать уже потом с нормальной ссылки на .jpeg.

Как получить список ссылок всех картинок, чтобы потом просто вставить в download master, к примеру?

Пытался использовать скрипт на питоне, но что-то не особо.

Comment: `Пытался аичать на питоне скрипт, но что-то не особо.` вот тут подробнее и желательно с вашим кодом, и тогда шанс получить ответ будет приближен к 100% :)

Comment: так как кода нет, то думаю логика такая сначала получить все ссылки с большими изображениями(с помощью регулярных выражений), а потом записать их в массив и в конце в цикле обработать получившийся  массив.

Answer (score 0):

Что мы имеем? Ссылка вида

> https://thepaperwall.com/category/cars/all/default/all/200?page=1

Проставляем в `DownLoadMaster` вместо `1` - `$` и до каких пор.

Скачиваем, ищем регуляркой (в другой программе) ссылки, сортируем, отбираем ссылки вида

> https://thepaperwall.com/wallpaper/123456

Сохраняем в файл. Скачиваем в `DownLoadMaster` списком `Файл -> Импорт -> URL из файла`. Ищем в страницах регуляркой ссылки вида

> https://thepaperwall.com/uploads/images/2017/12/17/0060668001513538446.jpeg

Сортируем, отбираем, сохраняем в файл, скачиваем в `DownLoadMaster` списком `Файл -> Импорт -> URL из файла`